# Password expiration in 14 to 45 days using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We used a **devise gem** for Login functionality.
Now i want to implement the **password expiration functionality**.
So i got one devise gem i.e "**devise_security_extension**" on git hub.

I read this documentation for implementation of "devise_security_extension".

I tried the steps from documentation.But it is not working for me.

Can any one give step by step process to implement this "devise_security_extension" gem.

Comment: do you have a solution? @user2622247, because I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I spotted [this question](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/issues/83) on the devise_security_extension issues page, I know it's been a while for you, but it might work. That leads to [this fix](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/pull/88), which I am going to try and implement tonight.

I'll report back if it helps

Comment: Thanks, just let me know your feedback.

Comment: So far, I haven't been able to get it to play nicely.